# Merge two datatable in to one datatable and remove duplicate as per single column

Tags: c#, datatable

I have two datatable, say T1 and T2. Following are the columns in both table:

```
1) Filename,
2) Size,
3) PATH,
4) rank,
5) DocTitle,
6) HitCount
```

Now, I need to merge table T1 and T2 but entries should not get duplicated as per "Filename" column.

I cant user `T1.Merge(T2)` to do my work. Do anyone have suggestion on the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to implement this in C# than smth like that could work for you

```
var fileNames = t1.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(row => row["FileName"]).ToList();
var rowsToAdd = t2.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Where(row => !fileNames.Contains(row["FileName"])).ToList();

foreach (var dataRow in rowsToAdd)
{
    t1.ImportRow(dataRow);
}
```

but it's better to use SQL filters and after that to put in DataTable.

Comment: I cant use SQL filter as I am working with Indexing services.

Comment: Following code worked for me :                                               foreach (DataRow r in T2.Rows)
            {
                DataRow[] dr= T1.Select("Filename='" + r["Filename"].ToString()+"'");
                if (dr.Count() == 0)
                {
                    //dtContents.Rows.Add(r);
                    T1.ImportRow(r);
                }
            }

Answer (score 0):

```
select * into table_name from (select * from T1  union select * from t2 )
```

**NOTE**

It will work only and only when both of table have same number of columns

Comment: it will have duplicated rows (by FileName column)